# Attempt to invoke virtual method | Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Перешел на котлин и появилась вот такая ошибка:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sirextech.readerui_kt/com.sirextech.readerui_kt.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

В чем проблема? Когда работал с Java такой ошибки не было.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_main_view)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host_fragment)
    Log.i("asda", navController.toString());
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_explore, R.id.nav_lib), drawerLayout)

    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Ошибка возникает вот на этой строке:

```
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не вижу полностью вашего кода. Поэтому точно не могу сказать. Но думаю, что ваша проблема не в этом коде, здесь вроде все ок.

Исходя из ошибки

```
void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)'
on a null object reference
```

Я думаю что вам нужно полезть в ваш ActionBar и посмотреть где вы пытаетесь засетить ваш title. У вас либо сам `ActionBar = null` либо передаваемый `title = null`.

Comment: Да, я покапался и понял, что у меня toolbar не вызывался, а тема этого требовала. Создал toolbar и все заработало.